# Issue with centering text

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation layer, and I cannot seem to get the links to center within.

This is the stylesheet I am using

```
.Layer1 {
    position:absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 95%;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    background-color: #D2FFFF;
}
.Layer1 a {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #0066FF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Using standard a href links makes no difference, nor does specifying the style to be a href. I am wondering what I am missing.

Comment: Can you post the html? Without it, it´s pretty hard to tell.

Comment: More information (like the HTML jeroen requested) would really be helpful. From what's given at this point, "text-align: center" will do nothing since anchor tags are inline elements. The width of .Layer1 could also be a problem, but again, more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links are inline elements, so setting text-align center on them won't achieve anything. Try making the link a block with an assigned width and then applying text-align center.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding:

```
text-align: center;
```

to .Layer1 {}?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by your style properties that you are applying them to a `<ul>` element. They have pretty wacky default padding/margin properties (a good reason to always use a [`reset`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)). If you set the `text-align: center;` as suggested by Stuart AND then set `padding: 0;` it will be centered as you might expect. Just tested it on IE and FF.

Comment: I was trying to apply them to the a href tags.

Answer (score 0):

Is layer 1 a `div` or a `ul`? if it is a `div`, `text-align: center` should work, as long as you haven't set `display: block` on your a tags.

to center a block element, you need to use `margin: auto`. to center an inline element, it is `text-align: center`. if that doesn't work, it has to do with your markup, or some other way that styles are getting overridden. I would highly suggest using firebug to see what is going on, I used to have these "wtf is going on" moments all the time with html, but since getting good with firebug they rarely last more then a few minutes.

The other thing is `text-indent` is for indenting the first line of a paragraph. use `padding-left` to add whitespace inside a block element, or `margin-left` to add it outside.

Comment: layer 1 is a div, and i wanted #layer 1 a to set the style for a href links in that div.